# How to open all UPI apps installed in phone inside Ionic App

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic4, deep-linking, webintents, upi

I am integrating UPI payment in my Ionic App.

I have injected WebIntent in the constructor of payment.ts and I call method upi() defined in payment.ts on **Pay button** click in payment.html

upi method defination :

```
upi(){
const options = {
  action : this.webIntent.ACTION_VIEW,
  url : 'upi://pay?pa=8400000701@upi&pn=game&tid=cxnkjcnkjdfdvjndkjfvn&tr=4894398cndhcd23&am=10&cu=INR&tn=App Payment'
};
// Open the intent with options
this.webIntent.startActivityForResult(options).then(onSuccess=> {
console.log('Success', onSuccess);
alert('Payment Successfully done.');
},
onError=> {
alert('error');
});
}
```

I am using Ionic V4 with Cordova and testing the app on my android device.
On pressing **Pay button** installed UPI apps are not being shown and alert('error') is being executed always. 
Please help me with this.

Comment: Is this resolved? If so, can you share the solution?

Comment: @kpvsrkp No, it has been not resolved.